# Setting Apache on BigSur (returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: apache-2.4, mac-osx, localhost

Firstly I've read many tutorials, I'm trying for many hours during last days (because I know there were billion similar questions and tutorials for the same thing before) but I'm in the ends... :-(

The last site I've followed (and checked many times) was https://tech-cookbook.com/2020/11/14/setting-up-your-local-web-server-on-macos-big-sur-11-0-1-2020-mamp-macos-apache-mysql-php/. Before I've tried https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-run-apache-php-on-mac-os-big-sur-7ffbf7cbef7b, but they looks very similar.

**What I have**

- Apache 2.4.46 (apachectl -v)
- php 7.3.24 (php -v)
- Apache should be setted correctly. Stopped and started.
- `sudo apachectl configtest` returns `Syntax OK`
- in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` I have set `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory ...` to `/Users/username/Sites/`
- `/Users/username/Sites` has chmod 777
- `/Users/username/Sites` shows me directory content (path is correct)
- `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` is set to (source https://wpbeaches.com/set-up-virtual-hosts-on-macos-big-sur-11-in-apache/)

  ```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /Users/username/Sites/ 
        # I've tried: 
        ## insert value into "",
        ## localhost, 
        ## localhost/~username, 
        ## set localhost and ServerAlias to localhost/~username, etc.
    </VirtualHost>
  ```

**Result**
As result, both `http://localhost` and `http://localhost/~username` returns me `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I've checked all `.conf` files settings with my older macbook and they look very similar in both machines... :-(

Any idea where could be problem? I'm able to put here more additional information (copy conf files content, whatever) if needed... I'm a little bit hopeless... :-(

Thanks!

**EDIT**

`ps -ax | grep '[h]ttpd'` returns

```
14994 ??         0:00.51 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
14997 ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
15002 ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
15040 ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
15042 ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
15043 ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

`sudo lsof -a -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -c httpd` returns

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   14994 root    4u  IPv6 0xbbfd6axxxxxxxxxx      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   14997 _www    4u  IPv6 0xbbfd6axxxxxxxxxx      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   15002 _www    4u  IPv6 0xbbfd6axxxxxxxxxx      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   15040 _www    4u  IPv6 0xbbfd6axxxxxxxxxx      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   15042 _www    4u  IPv6 0xbbfd6axxxxxxxxxx      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   15043 _www    4u  IPv6 0xbbfd6axxxxxxxxxx      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Is Apache actually running? Check with `ps -ax | grep '[h]ttpd'` (note that if it is running, you'll probably see several processes.) If it's running, check whether it's listening for incoming connections with `sudo lsof -a -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -c httpd`

Comment: @GordonDavisson thx for your comment. Both outputs are added into the question (sorry, I'm not able to tell if it's running from it)

Comment: The `lsof` output indicates it's listening for IPv6 connections, but not for IPv4; I don't know what'd cause that, but that's what I'd concentrate on trying to find. Actually, one more test: run `netstat -anv | grep '[.]80 .*LISTEN'` -- you'll see a line starting with `tcp6` showing that it's listening on TCP over IPv4, but does is also show one starting with `tcp4`? If so, that'd show that something else is grabbing the port on IPv4, and preventing Apache from getting it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I'm getting this `tcp46    0    0  *.80     *.*     LISTEN      131072 131072  18249    0 0x0080 0x0000000e`

Comment: @GordonDavisson: _If so, that'd show that something else is grabbing the port on IPv4, and preventing Apache from getting it. _... what does it mean, or what I should to do? I'm totally lost... :-(

Comment: Actually, that means I misinterpreted the `lsof` output -- it's actually listening for both IPv6 and IPv4 (that's what the "tcp46" at the beginning of the `netstat` output means), and `lsof` was only showing v6 for some reason. So... this isn't the problem. But it does mean that Apache is running and listening for connections, which basically means it (and its config files and whatnot) are *not* the problem. So look at your network config; things like any firewalls you're running, proxies, weird network/VPN configs, etc.

Comment: Also, rather than using "localhost", try an explicit address: `http://127.0.0.1/`. I'd also try from the command line, with `curl http://127.0.0.1/`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson No VPN, no proxy... :-( `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` do the same (redirected automatically to https and `err_connection_refused`). `curl http://127.0.0.1` returns `302`, `curl https://127.0.0.1` (or `https://localhost`) returns `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused`... It looks like problem is in automatically redirect to https (I've tried to google it, and I didn't find a way how to disable it)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I've set HTTPS - browser marks URL as not safe, but it works... Green lock in URL I can solve later... thanks for your time!